# Is every symmetric group generated by some cycles?

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups, dihedral-groups

Actually, I have two questions here:

1. How to show that $D_3$, the dihedral group, is isomorphic to $S_3$ in details?
2. Is every symmetric group generated by some cycles?

For question (1), I know that, apart from considering the symmetry of triangle, I can also define the isomorphism explicitly, namely, $\phi:D_3 \rightarrow S_3$, $a \mapsto [1,2,3]$, $b \mapsto [1,2]$, where $a$ and $b$ are the generators of $D_3$. It all makes sense to me but I find it hard to prove that $\phi$ is actually a homomorphism.

I come up with question (2) by observing the solution of question (1). In question (1), we make use of the fact that $S_3$ is generated by $[1,2,3]$ and $[1,2]$. But is it true that, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $S_n$ is generated by some cycles?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For $n\ge 2$, $S_n$ is generated by $(1\,2\,\ldots\,n)$ and $(1\,2)$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Why is it true? Is it even unique?

Comment: With groups so small as $\;D_3,S_3\;$ you can write down specifically all the elements and come up with some ideas about the isomorphism.

Comment: Finding generators for $S_n$ isn't unique at all. One could for instance add as many other cycles to the set of generators as well. Apart from the one Hagen von Eitzen mentioned, another popular set of generators consists of all cycles $(1\ i)$ for $2\leq i\leq n$.